# Deploy multiple linked ARM templates in Private Storage Container using single SAS token

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-rm-template

I have a master ARM template that has 3 linked child templates located in a private storage in Azure. In order to deploy each of the linked templates I need to generate and pass 3 blob SAS (shared access signature) tokens(one each per template) and append it to the URI of the ARM template.

Is it possible to access all these 3 ARM templates in the private storage using a single SAS token (may be a container token)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you could generate container-level shared access signature URI in the **Azure Storage Explorer** to access it.

Right-click your file -> Get SAS -> choose the option in the screenshot

[image]

Or generate SAS token **in the Azure portal**, you could set allowed services and more details in it.

[image]